# Error when checking length of a string. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length

Tags: c#

Note: I am not using substring.

Why would this cause the index and length location error? Note: Specifically, the piece which causes it is the if statement which checks the length of PONumber --- which btw: at the time of execution has a value who's length is 11 characters.

```
[StringLength(41)]
private string _EXTENDEDDESCRIPTION;
public string EXTENDEDDESCRIPTION
{
    get { return _EXTENDEDDESCRIPTION; }
    set { _EXTENDEDDESCRIPTION = value; }
}
public string PONumber { get; set; }


//Note, this is embedded inside a save method for the class
if ((this.EXTENDEDDESCRIPTION ?? string.Empty) == string.Empty)
{
    if (this.PONumber.Length <= 41)
    {
        this.EXTENDEDDESCRIPTION = this.PONumber;
    }
}
```

Causes this error:

```
Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length
  at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
```

Unfortunately, i cannot replicate this issue when debugging locally and I have to rely on logging to tell me what / if anything is different on production. But, I know the PONumber has a length. It is a non-nullable string. It should return at least 0. In my production situation it has a length of 11, which if I remove the if statement and just let EXTENDEDDESCRIPTION get set regardless, it gets the 11 character value from PONumber.

Comment: Strings are reference types in C# and can always be set to null. Aside from that, do you have any fancy exception handling going on? I suspect there is a `try...catch` thats just rethrowing and its hiding the real issue.

Comment: Sure... but I would have to be explicitly setting it to null. Regardless, the string has a length in this case.


Catch is simple. 

   catch (Exception ex)
   {   Helper.WriteToLog(ex, LoggingLevels.Error);
       throw ex;
   }

Comment: Thats interesting. Can you see if `Helper.WriteToLog()` is performing a substring?

Comment: Try passing `ErrorMessage="some error message"` to see if it is getting thrown.  I could be wrong but I believe the substring is happening when you are trying to set the string

Comment: Also catching `Exception` is a bad idea. An out of memeory exception, or stackoverflow execption would blow up. Prefer to use application level expection handling, unless you can recover from it gracefully

Comment: No substring in the WriteToLog. Its just a 5 liner which calls log for net and throws an exception if it can't call log4net for some reason.

Literally... no substring in the entire solution!

Comment: That's an interesting theory Ballbin...

That property doesn't get set in this solution. But, what you're saying seems possible. It's getting set via a DDS from a silverlight client.

Comment: Meant to say, the property doesn't get set in the project. It could be set in the client project.

5:30PM my time... already left and will look more if it's a client side problem tomorrow. Thank you all for the responses. I already solved with a work around and deployed it. But, I want to know why this failed and will work on it again tomorrow morning.

Comment: @maplemale can you post the entire stack trace?  This should show the caller of System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks, and its caller, and so on.

Comment: I can't post the entire stack trace... can't reproduce this in debug. Ultimately discovered, I was not logging the correct error - partially due to Jay's comment above.

Which... led me to the ultimate solution which is pandeSai's answer below. Since this error can only be thrown by a substring which definitely isn't being used here, it must be bubbling up from somewhere else - which it was.

Answer (score 1):

You stated that you are not using substring, but that function (InternalSubStringWithChecks) is only called by Substring in all the framework (take a decompiler and look at it, it's only called by Substring).

Maybe it's not your code the one which throws the exceptions, you are missing the full stack trace (at least is not posted here, how are you sure that's the piece of code generating the exception?), maybe digging a bit more in the stack can shed some light.

Comment: Sometimes knowing a probable cause is completely impossible is key in leading one to the correct answer as your first sentence did.

You were correct, the code was coming from a completely different area than I thought it was (from the client in this case) and went away when I altered the .length piece of code, but only because I also released a new version of the client which did not have the erroneous code in it. 

Long story short: You were right it 100% has to be a substring causing this. Also, as pointed out by Jay above, I wasn't catching the exact error.